# How to map excel/csv data values to existing json template?

Tags: python, json, csv

I've excel sheet having all the required values mentioned in a row format & have existing sample json template. Now i would like to map the excel row data value to the existing json template. How this could be achieved ? pls guide.

I checked some of the python codes but they are converting csv data to python
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-csv-to-json-using-python/

but here the requirement is to map excel values to json template .

Comment: If you can convert to python you can convert to JSON.